# Ansible Roles and vars/vault.yml file

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I usually use `encrypt_string` for encrypting secrets in my ansible roles but I have a new boss and he insists on encrypting the whole file but I cannot not seem to get that to work with an Ansible role.

Here is a simple example that illustrates what my problem is.

```
bash-3.2$ tree
.
├── playbooks
│   └── run_foo.yml
└── roles
    └── foo
        ├── tasks
        │   └── main.yml
        └── vars
            ├── main.yml
            └── vault.yml

5 directories, 4 files
```

Here is a playbook that uses the role.

```
bash-3.2$ cat playbooks/run_foo.yml
---
- name: Run Foo
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - role: ../roles/foo
```

Here's the role:

```
bash-3.2$ cat roles/foo/tasks/main.yml
---
# tasks file for foo
- name: Show us debug clear_text
  debug:
    var: clear_text
- name: Show us debug password
  debug:
    var: password
```

Here is my vars/main.yml file:

```
bash-3.2$ cat roles/foo/vars/main.yml
---
# vars file for foo
include_vars: vault.yml
clear_text: 12345
```

Here is my encrypted `vault.yml` file:

```
bash-3.2$ cat roles/foo/vars/vault.yml
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
64653334323939303461653839353634666162383130326533306234636232656162306661383761
6339376233366638643331373831316638373263663830350a333733653039353939656633376333
31323232666633373633393032396232613830393735396139376333353035633566376465636536
3930633964633861620a633735343066313938633733303538333864353665393062626338356665
63363666636638623964336461346366323565323563316434323439626239633734
```

This is what it looks like decrypted:

```
bash-3.2$ ansible-vault view roles/foo/vars/vault.yml
Vault password:
password: hovercraft
```

Here's what happens when I run the playbook:

```
bash-3.2$ ansible-playbook -i,localhost playbooks/run_foo.yml --connection=local --ask-vault-pass
Vault password:

PLAY [Run Foo] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: error loading fact - please check content
[WARNING]: Platform darwin on host localhost is using the discovered Python interpreter at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6, but future installation of
another Python interpreter could change the meaning of that path. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.
ok: [localhost]

TASK [../roles/foo : Show us debug clear_text] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "clear_text": 12345
}

TASK [../roles/foo : Show us debug password] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "password": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Is it possible to use a encrypted vault.yml file like my new manager wants?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put both files into the directory *vars/main*. All files in *vars/main* are included automatically. For example,

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── roles
│   └── foo
│       ├── tasks
│       │   └── main.yml
│       └── vars
│           └── main
│               ├── main.yml
│               └── vault.yml
└── run_foo.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/foo/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    var: clear_text
- debug:
    var: password
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/foo/vars/main/main.yml 
clear_text: 12345
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/foo/vars/main/vault.yml 
password: hovercraft
```

```yaml
shell> cat run_foo.yml 
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - foo
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat hosts
localhost
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook run_foo.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [foo : debug] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  clear_text: 12345

TASK [foo : debug] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  password: hovercraft

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

You'll get the same result with encrypted *vault.yml*. Encrypting the whole file is simpler and safer. Instead of the code, you update and encrypt this single file only. In addition to this, a use case is possible where each user maps its own *vault.yml* overlay.

**Notes**

1. Use the role's directory *defaults*

Don't distribute roles with the directory *vars/main* or file *vars/main.yml*. The purpose of the role's *vars* is to override the role's *defaults*. See [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). An update of a role will overwrite potential user's customization in *vars* if you distribute it. In development, ignore *vars/main* in your version control.

Put *vault.yml* into the directory *defaults*

```yaml
shell> cat roles/foo/defaults/main/vault.yml 
password: hovercraft
```

and test the password

```yaml
shell> cat roles/foo/tasks/main.yml
- assert:
    that: password != 'hovercraft'
    fail_msg: Change and encrypt password!
  when: assert_password|d(true)|bool

- debug:
    var: clear_text
- debug:
    var: password
```

By default, the user'll see

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook run_foo.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [foo : assert] **************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: password != 'hovercraft'
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Change and encrypt password!
```

Turn the *assert* off for testing

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook run_foo.yml -e assert_password=false
```

2. Limit the scope of secrets

You can limit the scope of secrets to the tasks where you need them. For example, put the password to a file

```
shell> cat vars/password.yml 
my secret password
```

and read it in the tasks

```yaml
shell> cat roles/foo/tasks/main.yml 
- assert:
    that: password != 'hovercraft'
    fail_msg: Change and encrypt password!
  when: assert_password|d(true)|bool
  vars:
    password: "{{ lookup('file', password_path) }}"

- debug:
    var: clear_text
- debug:
    var: password
  vars:
    password: "{{ lookup('file', password_path) }}"
```

Provide the path to the file, for example, in the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat run_foo.yml 
- hosts: all
  vars:
    password_path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/vars/password.yml"
  roles:
    - foo
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook run_foo.yml

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [foo : assert] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed

TASK [foo : debug] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  clear_text: 12345

TASK [foo : debug] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  password: my secret password

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The encryption of the files is transparent to the *file* lookup. This also solves your other problem to `"use grep to find things in the code"`

```yaml
shell> grep -r password: roles/
roles/foo/defaults/main/vault.yml:password: hovercraft
roles/foo/tasks/main.yml:    password: "{{ lookup('file', password_path) }}"
roles/foo/tasks/main.yml:    password: "{{ lookup('file', password_path) }}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Like I mentioned in my OP I prefer to use `encrypt_string` instead of encrypting the whole file mostly because I like to use `grep` to find things in my code.  Other than using a comment is there a way around this small short coming?

Comment: There are plenty of options. I added an example. For advanced options see [*community.general.passwordstore*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/passwordstore_lookup.html). For example [*Create, or update passwords of selected users at remote hosts*](https://ansible-linux-postinstall.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide-task-passwords-passwordstore.html).

Comment: I wish i could give this answer more upvotes. Incredible work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use `include_vars` in a vars file. That doesn't work; `include_vars` is an Ansible module and will only work a task list (i.e., a playbook, role, or similar). So you can write `roles/foo/tasks/main.yaml` like this:

```
- name: load encrypted vars
  include_vars:
    file: vault.yaml

- name: show us debug clear_text
  debug:
    var: clear_text

- name: show us debug password
  debug:
    var: password
```

Assuming that you have `roles/foo/vars/main.yaml` that looks like this:

```
clear_text: this is clear text
```

And `roles/foo/vars/vault.yaml` that you created like this:

```
echo 'password: hovercraft' |
  ansible-vault encrypt > roles/foo/vars/vault.yaml
```

We can write a playbook like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - foo
```

And run it like this:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --ask-vault-password
```

And get the following output:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [foo : load encrypted vars] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [foo : show us debug clear_text] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "clear_text": "this is clear text"
}

TASK [foo : show us debug password] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "password": "hovercraft"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

You can find a complete example [in this repository](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-75991358-ansible-vault).

---

If you want the encrypted file to load automatically without requiring an explicit `include_vars`, then move it out of the role and into `group_vars` or `host_vars`.